I don't understand how decision boundary is working in this case!! (related to sigmoid function)

This is a sigmoid graph performed on some random data.
I don’t understand the difference between the- 0.5 threshold border and the orange line which is the decision boundary… isn’t the decision boundary supposed to divide the positive and negative regions, im really confused, then why is the vertical line doing its job here, it’s clear that the vertical line is separating the two regions, why is that, then what is the importance of the orange line i.e. the decision boundary…
that vertical line corresponds to the point where sigmoid is 0.5, above which the category should be positive, but then what does decision boundary is doing here, please clarify
